# Access public properties parent class from an extended public function class

Tags: php, function, class, properties, public

i'm a newbie on PHP, here is my code

```
class number_config{
    public $length = 200, //declare a properties
           $width = 100,
           $height = 300;
}

class formula extends number_config{
        public function rectangular_prism(){
            $volume = $length * $width * $height;
            echo 'The rectangular prism volume is: '. $volume .'meter cubic';
         // i want this echo produce this,
         // The rectangular prism volume is: 6000000 meter cubic

         //set the new member_config properties value
            $length = 600;
            $width = 1000;
            $height = 400;
        }

        public function rectangular_prism2(){
            $volume = $length * $width * $height;
            echo 'The rectangular prism volume is: '. $volume .'meter cubic';
         // i want this echo produce this,
         // The rectangular prism volume is: 240000000 meter cubic

      //and then set the other new member_config properties value, and so on
            $length = 800;
            $width = 2000;
            $height = 300;
        }

}
$rectangular_prism_volume = new formula();
echo $rectangular_prism_volume->rectangular_prism();
echo $rectangular_prism_volume->rectangular_prism2();
```

firstly, i'm sorry for this silly php code,
I'm a newbie, and just try to practicing :)
That codes doesn't work,
it's print out an error

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: width in **xxx.php** on line **11**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: length in **xxx.php** on line **11**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: height in **xxx.php** on line **11**
>   The rectangular prism volume is: 0meter cubic
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: width in **xxx.php** on line **23**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: length in **xxx.php** on line **23**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: height in **xxx.php** on line **23**
>   The rectangular prism volume is: 0meter cubic

Things that i want to ask is how to get the properties of that parent class
on a function, and assign a new properties value that overwrite the width, length, height, properties value
Thank you for anyone who helped me on this case :)

Comment: Use `$this->width`, etc to access object properties from within the an instance of the class

Comment: Wow.. that was so fast man.. :D thank you for your help, it's solves everything, even if i'm using that with a protected properties :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better approach for what you are trying to do, use set and get method to set the member values when you want and then get it.

```
class number_config{
    public  $length = 200; //declare a properties
    public  $width = 100;
    public  $height = 300;

        public function setLength($l){
             $this->length = $l;
        }

        public function setWidth($w){
             $this->width = $w;
        }

        public function setHeight($h){
             $this->height = $h;
        }

        public function getLength(){
            return $this->length ;
        }

        public function getWidth(){
            return $this->width ;
        }

        public function getHeight(){
            return $this->height ;
        }

}

class formula extends number_config{
        public function rectangular_prism(){
            $volume = $this->getLength() * $this->getWidth() * $this->getHeight();
            echo 'The rectangular prism volume is: '. $volume .'meter cubic';
        }

        public function rectangular_prism2(){
            $volume = $this->getLength() * $this->getWidth() * $this->getHeight();
            echo 'The rectangular prism volume is: '. $volume .'meter cubic';

        }

}

$formula = new formula();

//call the function rectangular_prism() with some values
$formula->setLength(600);
$formula->setWidth(1000);
$formula->setHeight(400);
$formula->rectangular_prism();

//call the function rectangular_prism2() with some values
$formula->setLength(800);
$formula->setWidth(2000);
$formula->setHeight(300);
$formula->rectangular_prism2();
```

Comment: it's good to see your code, but unfortunately, i'm not only using 3 properties, i'm using 20 or more properties right now. And i don't want pass the value into a function parameter :) if you got a better code, show me then ;)

Comment: I see if you have more properties and you want them use on the fly then the best would be use the "object->property = val" since as you said it could be more than 20. The above is an example to illustrate the code flow. However you can see magic methods like __get() and __set() they are useful when you dont know how many properties you may have and can be used to set and get dynamically.